# API call using axios in React best practices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am calling a backend API to get a product in my frontend React application using async/await axios. For this call I defined a function as below:

```
export const getProduct = ():Promise<Product> => {
  const {data} = await axios.get<Product>('http://myurl.com/api/getproduct');
  return data;
}
```

Alternatively I can use the code below to return everything returned by get,

```
export const getProduct = ():Promise<AxiosResponse<Product>> => {
  return axios.get<Product>('http://myurl.com/api/getproduct');
}
```

I was wondering if there is any best practice recommendation for choosing one over another.

Comment: Why force clients to deal with `AxiosResponse`? What if you replace `axios` with Javascript's `fetch`? Should all clients change as well?

Comment: I have to use axios as a member of a big team.

Comment: You don't have to leak it though. Especially in large teams and projects, you *don't* want the implementation details of one call or module to leak to others. There's no good reason why the caller of `getProducts` should know anything about how it's loaded. What if you decide to load cache it and load it from session storage?

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to not return everything, normally you implement a class that hides HTTP interface. You can name it service, client or sdk, doesn't matter. But what is the matter you do not expose implementation specifics (like HTTP response) and return only what you need (the data). Especially the name of your function is `getProduct`, so it is supposed to return a product, not the HTTP response.